# React Native App Crashes and Keeps Stopping Only When Testing the Release Build

Tags: android, react-native

When testing in debug mode using `yarn run android`, my React Native app builds successfully and launches fine without any errors. However, after creating the android release APK and trying to test the release build of the app using `npx react-native run-android --variant=release` the app crashes on startup and keeps stopping giving this error in `adb logcat`.

`Requested enabled DevSupportManager, but DevSupportManagerImpl class was not found or could not be created.`
`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:  Didn't find class "com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSupportManagerImpl" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~mOnjxIae7sfF7KVVJG8A1Q==/com.plasticdisposalapp-TgQRbvXhWfBJDS3VuUEMtQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~mOnjxIae7sfF7KVVJG8A1Q==/com.plasticdisposalapp-TgQRbvXhWfBJDS3VuUEMtQ==/lib/arm64, /data/app/~~mOnjxIae7sfF7KVVJG8A1Q==/com.plasticdisposalapp-TgQRbvXhWfBJDS3VuUEMtQ==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/product/lib64]]`

I'm using "react-native": "0.63.2", "gradle-6.9" and "minSdkVersion = 21"

I've searched for solutions and tried those workarounds, but unfortunately still couldn't find a working method for fixing this issue. Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: Hi KH Evolve, Check this github issue and this might be helpful https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28481#issuecomment-645546195

Comment: I'll refer, Thanks EL173